# proof of the sample mean being the unbiased estimator of population mean in Simple Random Sampling with Replacement

Tags: statistics, sampling-theory

Im'm looking for the simplest proof of the sample mean being the unbiased estimator of population mean in Simple Random Sampling with Replacement.

I searched for this in literature in my native language but I couldn't find anything satisfactory. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With appropriate definitions, and bits of explanation:

$E(\bar X) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = \frac{1}{n}n\mu = \mu.$